# How to Sync Project with Gradle Files?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

1. change gradle.properties by a script ;
2. manual Sync Project so the resVal and BuildConfig will refresh.

so, what does the manual Sync Project button do?
how to manual write it in my cmd script

Comment: I think this command main does your thing ./gradlew build

Comment: i just want sync，not build,build do much more work

Answer (score 0):

May bellow tow thing will do your work

If you want to sync just project without rebuild then use bellow command

```
./gradlew --recompile-scripts
```

And if you want to rebuild your full project

```
./gradlew build
```

And Also if you want to see your all task then use bellow commands

```
./gradlew tasks
```

Comment: not working for my gradle "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1",there's no  --recompile-scripts option